# API to read extensions in a CDS view

Tags: abap, cds

I want to know name of all existing extensions in CDS view.
Is there any FM or class which can help here?

Is there any FM or class which can help here?

Any class in which, if I give CDS view, it returns all existing extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `CL_DD_DDL_EXTENSION_HANDLER` and method `GET_EXTENSION_DDLNAMES` takes the base CDS view name as input, and returns all the CDS views that extend the given view in a table format.